# MVC ERRor: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a SearchController

```
  public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        var vm = new SearchViewModel();
        var list = _db.Intrusts.ToList();
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(new Tuple<SearchViewModel, PagedList.IPagedList<Intrust>>(vm, list.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10)));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Tuple<SearchViewModel, PagedList.IPagedList<Intrust>> model)
    {
        var vm = model.Item1;
        var list = _db.Intrusts.ToList();
        if (vm.Code != null)
            list = list.Where(m => m.Code == vm.Code).ToList();


        return View("Index", new Tuple<SearchViewModel, PagedList.IPagedList<Intrust>>(vm, list.ToPagedList(1, 10)));
    }
```

and in view

```
@model Tuple<_6badgiri.ViewModels.SearchViewModel, PagedList.IPagedList<_6badgiri.Models.Intrust>>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<div class="row">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Item1.StateId)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item1.StateId, new SelectList(area, "Id", "Name"))
</div>
 <input type="submit" value="جستجو " id="btnsubmit" class="wpb_button btn td-login-button green" />
}
```

but when i click in submit button , i get error `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

Comment: Your form is being posted to `Search` action, where is it?

Comment: *Where* do you get the exception, what is the exception stack? Does you controller have a constructor? Is your controller named `SearchController` or are you posting to a different controller? The code you posted is irrelevant, unless the exception occurs in a line there

Comment: Sorry, it is searchController, plz see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Tuple<T1, T2>` doesn't have a default constructor, so the default model-binder can't initialize it.

You should either use another appropriate type or implement a custom model-binder to bind to `Tuple` type

Comment: You can create a viewmodel that will contain both models

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like Below

Here I have changed the code in 3rd line as Search to Index. Because you are using the **Search** action method instead of **Index**

```
@model Tuple<_6badgiri.ViewModels.SearchViewModel, 
PagedList.IPagedList<_6badgiri.Models.Intrust>>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<div class="row">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Item1.StateId)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item1.StateId, new SelectList(area, "Id", "Name"))
</div>
 <input type="submit" value="جستجو " id="btnsubmit" class="wpb_button btn td-login-button green" />
}
```